# Objective-c++ coding style / code formatting

Tags: c++, code-beautification

I am looking for a way to automate the coding style of my Objective-C++ code (a mix of Objective-C and C++).

I played with Uncrustify: it works great with Objective-C or C++ but when trying to format an Objective-C++ code, it's another story: sometimes it formats C++ code as Objc, and Objc code as C++.

Is there any tool that handle Objective-C++ properly?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you need, [GNU Indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html) might do the trick. It has customisable indentation and formatting rules, which I guess you could tweak to suit your particular code. I don't know much about Obj-C though, so it might fall over when trying to deal with that.